# before pseudo element in element markup?

Tags: html, css, html-email, pseudo-element

I'm trying to style a preceding element in an html email.  Since Outlook doesn't support css classes I'm trying to do this in element markup, but it's not working.  Is it possible to use a before pseudo element in css that's an element's markup?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test before</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>I wanna be red</div>
<div style="before:: color:red">I'm not red</div>
<div>I'm just hanging out</div>
<div style="color:red">I'm red</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it is [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before), and it is a selector, which you cannot use in the style attribute of an element. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: That's not what before does.